# How can I find time difference between two same audio signals?

Tags: audio

How can I find time difference between two same audio signals?
Please do not answer cross-correlation or GCC. I am looking up for a new solution that will help me. Thank you.

Comment: This topic was already addressed here: [Estimating the time offset](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/8737/estimating-the-time-offset-delay-between-two-audio-signals-in-real-time) together with great source: [click](http://www.control.isy.liu.se/research/reports/LicentiateThesis/Lic1061.pdf). Why is it not helpful?

Comment: -1: Really bad way to ask a question here.  Please tell us _why_ cross-correlation or GCC don't help you. You come across as not really interested in helping people to help you!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the magnitude has remained unchanged, instead of correlation, another possibility is to compute AMDF (magnitude difference) or ASDF (squared difference) between a range of shifts of the two waveforms.  Peak interpolation of the difference vector may be useful.